# How to make readonly SKU input in admin while product add/edit magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

How to make readonly SKU input in admin while product add/edit magento 2.3

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Readonly is not working in Magento UI form. If you want to disable that field then use the below code which I post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For disabled product SKU field in the admin.
Create `di.xml` file under `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml` with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sku" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Attributes</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

And create `Attributes.php` file under `app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/` with below content.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Attributes extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager
     */
    private $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * modifyData
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * modifyMeta
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $attribute = 'sku'; //attribute code to disable
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath($attribute, $meta, null, 'children');
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
            "{$path}/arguments/data/config/disabled",
            $meta,
            true
        );

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advanced.